# Is this definition of $(c\downarrow G)$ the slice category or is it something else?

Tags: category-theory

I'm learning about the slice and coslice category constructs, and I think I understand the basics from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Slice_category).

However, in [this](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~janschuetz/courses/cat/main.pdf) lecture script (in German), there's another definition given, which sounds similar, but I'm not sure if it's really the same, or just somehow related to the slice/coslice categories.

On page 20 (*Beispiel 2.4.18*), the comma category is defined:

> Let $C,D,E$ be categories and $F:C\to E$ and $G:D\to E$ be functors. First, we define the graph $(F\downarrow G)$, which has as objects triples $(c,d,f)$ with objects $c\in C,d\in D$ and a morphism $f:F(c)\to G(d)$. Between two objects $(c,d,f),(c',d',f')$, the arrows are pairs of morphisms $(\alpha:c\to c',\beta:d\to d')$ such that the diagram [...] commutes. Through the component-wise composition of arrows we get the category $(F\downarrow G)$.

On the next page (*Beispiel 2.4.19.(3)*), the following special case is given:

> If $C=E$ and $F:\{c\}\to C$ is the inclusion of one object $c\in C$, then we write $(c\downarrow G)$ instead of $(F\downarrow G)$.

This sounds very similar to the slice or coslice category $(\mathcal C\downarrow A)$ or $(A\downarrow\mathcal C)$ as defined in Wikipedia, but there are differences:

- In Wikipedia, one of the "source categories" is isomorphic to the target category while the other one is the terminal (one object, one morphism) category. In the lecture script, this "one-object inclusion functor" does not come from the terminal category but from the one that's isomorphic to the target category of both functors.
- In Wikipedia, the category under construction are noted as e.g. $(\mathcal C\downarrow A)$, which is *a category and an object*. In the lecture script, the notation is $(c\downarrow G)$, which is *an object and a functor*.

How are these definitions related to each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distinction in your first bullet is not what actually occurs. As the notation says, the inclusion functor $F$ has domain the terminal category $\{c\}$. There's a typo in the lecture notes: your last quote should begin "If $D=E$."

The author also fails to make clear that in the special case $G$ is meant to be the identity functor of $D$ (and of $E=D$.) So the two definitions agree, that is, $(\mathcal C\downarrow A)=(\text{id}_\mathcal{C}\downarrow c)$, in Wiki's and the lecturer's notation respectively.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?